# Issue with Release Pipeline in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, release, gitlab-ci-runner

Release pipeline is integrated with gitlab-ci.

Below is the snippet of code which is working if i add hard-coded value for tag_name:

```
release_job:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never                                  
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'develop'           
  script:
    - nextVersion=$(cat version.env)
    - echo "running release_job for $nextVersion"
  release:                                         
    tag_name: 0.0.2                   
    description: 0.0.2
```

But if i set snippet as below then nextVersion value is not getting pass to tag_name, also if we print nextVersion value in script section then its printing correct value.

```
release_job:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never                                  
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'develop'           
  script:
    - nextVersion=$(cat version.env)
    - echo "running release_job for $nextVersion"
  release:                                         
    tag_name: $nextVersion                   
    description: $nextVersion
```

How to overcome this issue, please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Used below snippet solved issue :

```
release_job:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never                                  
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'develop'           
  script:
    - nextVersion=$(cat version.env)
    - echo "running release_job for $nextVersion"
  release:                                         
    tag_name: $(cat version.env)                
    description: $(cat version.env)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).